# sql can't check column1>column2 not working

Tags: sql

I have some problem in sql syntax.

i have products table and below two column

1. total_quantity (Its total quantity for products)
2. remain_alert_quantity

i want to get records that are below remain_alert_quantity

```
select * from products where total_quantity<remain_alert_quantity
```

but its not work .
can i check condition with column value in sql.
thanks and regards.

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: What's not working? What's the message you're getting?

Comment: The query seems okay. What error are you getting? check for null values in columns, could be data problem

Comment: It won't return rows where one of the columns is null

Comment: there is no error ,but no true result sir

Answer (score 0):

Given data is not sufficient so I am assuming few thing like,

- you want to compare the product quantity with the remain_alert_quantity of same product.
- There is some unique column in table (like product_id)

in this case try the below query.

select * from products a where a.total_quantity<
(select b.remain_alert_quantity from products b where b.product_id=a.product_id);

Comment: sorry for my lack of resource

i want to get data from products table,that are out of stock product by given quantity,that quantity is alert_remain_quantity column.

products table
===========
id      name     total_quantity         alert_remain_quantity
1        p1           10                                3
2       p2            2                                 3


i want to get id 2 table because  its below 3(alert_remain_quantity)
but not return result by given sql sir
thanks you